# Eevee occluder material

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

Is it possible to create an occluder material in Eevee? i.e. have a material that only writes to the depth buffer, so the object will occlude objects behind it without rendering a visible color.

Like this in three.js / webGL – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion

Comment: Is this simply a Holdout, achievable as a [shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html#holdout), or as a [collection setting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html#holdout)? (slightly different from your example, without further compositing)

Comment: @RobinBetts ahh yes, this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @RobinBetts could you add your comment as an answer? I'll mark it as solved.